# Will Android x86 questions be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, question-appropriateness

With the release of [Android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) available for running the Android OS on a PC, will we be accepting questions that pertain to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering there are already a few [android-x86](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-x86) questions, I'd say yes.

A difficulty here is that there's likely to be overlap with [Super User](http://superuser.com). Issues that are Android-specific will be on-topic. People having trouble with installation because of their underlying hardware may not.

Answer (score 6):

As long as they are Android oriented questions, then I have no problem with them being here.